# How to get the html attribute value?

Tags: java, html

I would like to get the value of the "`value`" attribute on an HTML code wherein `class = validated` and save it to variable "`variationID`". How can i code that using java?

Here is the part of HTML code:

```
<input id="942981037_3-4" type="text" size="35" value="533" data-valid="-0123456789" class="validated"/>
```

File attached here: https://gofile.io/?c=mNiVcB

Here is the initial code I created:

```
String html = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); // get response from your sampler
String variationID;
Integer b;
for (int i = -1; (i = html.indexOf("class=\"validated\"", i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
    b = i;
}
b=b-30;
variationID = html.substring(b,b+3);
int res = Integer.parseInt(variationID) + 1;
variationID = res.toString();
log.info(variationID);
```

Comment: What is your expect output from us can u clearify what u want..

Comment: You need server side framework or servlet to deal with html inputs

Comment: I want to get 533 and save to a variable. There are a lot of /input elements/tag in the html but I will only get the value of "value" attribute where class="validated" and save it to variable

Comment: I have attached the html here: https://gofile.io/?c=mNiVcB

Comment: @Vegil Add java code also. Are you using servlets?

Comment: I am actually using BeanShell for my jmeter script and I have this initial code

Comment: @Vegil did u tried request.getParam?

Comment: Hello @JennisVaishnav, i tried getting the indexof  just to get the class="validated" then substring to get the value of the "value" attribute which I think is not flexible. See the code from my posted questions

Comment: @Vegil you want that value inside java class from html page, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several HTML parser libraries ([jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for example) but if youo need to use only the standard Java you can use a DocumentBuilder to parse your page

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;    
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;


    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    xmlStringBuilder.append("<html> <body><input id=\"942981037_3-4\" type=\"text\" size=\"35\" value=\"533\" data-valid=\"-0123456789\" class=\"validated\"/></body></html>");
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Document doc = builder.parse(input);
    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value"));
```

The example exactly fit your line but with an helper method you can extract any other element.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Regular Expressions instead.
You can simply write a regular expression to extract the attribute from the input tag. Refer the code below to extract the value of the attribute.

```
    String html = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); // get response from your sampler
    String variationID;

    // Pattern for finding input tag with class validated
    String input = "<input id=\"942981037_3-4\" type=\"text\" size=\"35\" value=\"533\" data-valid=\"-0123456789\" class=\"validated\"/>";
    // Compiling the pattern
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\<input.*(class=\".*validated.*\")?.*value=\"([\\w\\d]+)?\".*(class=\".*validated.*\")?.*/\\>");
    // Passing the input string to the pattern to start matching
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    // Iterate through all the matches in given string
    while(matcher.find()) {
        // If a match is found value will be found in group 2
        variationID = matcher.group(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to use RegEx, You can use more simple Java with String [split()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-split) method.

```
        String one = "<input id=\"942981037_3-4\" type=\"text\" size=\"35\" value=\"533\" data-valid=\"-0123456789\" class=\"validated\"/>";
        int variationID = -1;
        if (one.contains("value=\"")) {
            String part = one.split("value=\"")[1]; //Take everything from value=" forward
            String val = part.split("\"")[0]; //take stuff until first "
            try {
                variationID = Integer.parseInt(val);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Nope. I guess, the value is wrong");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(variationID);
```

Here You just split the string from **value="** forward. And when you get that, you can split the remaining part by the **"** and you will be left with what's in the middle.